# Letting people edit my notes without them having to create an account

Tags: web-apps, note-taking

I am searching a website where there's a free service with possibility to create notes. I should be able to fully manage my notes and the additional requirements are:

- it should be possible to create a table inside a note,
- I should be able to share my notes amongst people without an account within the website and these people should be able to edit my notes (anyone who's got the link). The visitors probably should have less power in editing my notes than I have.

The requirements above are a must. The requirements below are optional.

- I should be able to see the history of the note and be able to restore some old version.
- The size of a single cell in a table can be set by its height or number of words put inside the cell.
- It is possible to generate more than one link for one note and each link gives a visitor different rights of edition.

As far as I know, I could run my own [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_software) and it would satisfy these conditions almost fully. I'm looking for some simpler solution.

Comment: Have you tried [Cryptpad](https://cryptpad.fr/)? There are multiple sites providing pads. I remember having edited other people's documents (on their request) somewhere in the past, and I didn't create an account. I cannot tell about all your requirements, but as it's an entire office suite, I'd wonder if you'd miss something.